# Can I make a table of String + lambdas that have the same signature?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lambda, c++11

I have this pattern:

```
Thing * y = FindNearestItem();
if (y && (MenuElement * x = FindMenuElementNamed("Identity")))
  x->SetText(FString("%.1f", y));
else if (x)
  x->Clear();
if (y && (MenuElement * x = FindMenuElementNamed("X1")))
  x->SetLocalData(y);
else if (x)
  x->Clear();
```

Basically, I want to use a static table:
[WARNING: really sloppy conceptual code, not valid, I'm a noob, you've been warned]:

```
struct Table {
  const char * label;
  ?lambda? lambda;
} MyTable[] = {
  "Identity", [] (const char * label, Thing * y) { MenuElement * x = FindMenuElementNamed(label); (y && x) ? x->SetText(FString("%.1f", y)) : x->Clear(); },
  "X1", [] (const char * label, Thing * y) { MenuElement * x = FindMenuElementNamed(label); (y && x) ? x->SetLocalData(y) : x->Clear(); },
};

Thing * y = FindNearestItem();
for (int i = 0; i != countof(MyTable); ++i)
  MyTable[i].lambda(MyTable[i].label, y);
```

PLEASE keep in mind that that the action differs for each label - each row in my table.

So the pattern is mostly the same, but the variance is in the action taken, though it uses the same set of data (x,y,label) in each case.  But I cannot simply call x->DoAppropriateThingFor(label,y);  I'd just be back to creating a long if/else cascade based on label...

Feel free to ask me for further clarification.  I'm muddling around in the dark with lambdas since I've not had a chance to really use them yet...

Comment: I can think of some obvious improvements - like putting the if !x condition outside of the lambda since that is an invariant.  But I need to know if pursuing this makes sense at all. :)

Comment: I believe you will need a template here as you can't state a lambdas type name IIRC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as all of the lambdas are captureless (i.e., the `[]` is empty), you can use a function pointer:

```
struct Table {
    const char* label;
    void (*lambda)(const char*, Thing*);
};
```

If any of the lambdas are stateful (i.e., the `[]` is not empty), then you can't use a function pointer.  You can use `std::function`, though:

```
struct Table {
    const char* label;
    std::function<void(const char*, Thing*)> lambda;
};
```

Visual C++ 2010 does not support the lambda-to-function-pointer conversion (that conversion was added to the language after Visual C++ 2010 was released), but the Visual C++ 11 Developer Preview does support the conversion.  If you are using Visual C++ 2010, you can use the `std::function` solution.

Comment: It's going to hinge one whether the compiler allows the lambda syntax to be embedded int the static initialization list for the table...

Comment: @Mordachai:  I don't have Visual C++ 2010 installed anymore, but the Visual C++ 11 Developer Preview accepts both of these with the lambda in the static initializer of the table.

Comment: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from '`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>' to 'void (__cdecl *)(ITEM *,CDynamicMenuItem *)'

Comment: Right:  see the last paragraph of the answer.  Visual C++ 2010 **does not support** the lambda-to-function-pointer conversion.  It **does** support `std::function`, though.

Comment: Ah- thanks.  I failed to update my browser - didn't see your expanded answer.  That looks promising!

Comment: The `std::function` version is also good, because it doesn't require any particular callable type; you can use any callable thing. By taking a function pointer, you restrict usage only to degradable lambdas or actual function pointers.